# SQL Server (2005) target tables in different schemas from store procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, schema, role-based

Please can any one advise if it is possible to have a stored procedure in the [dbo] schema select data from one **table** in one **schema** for users accessing via one **database role** and for it to select data from a like-named **table** in another **schema** for users accessing via another **database role**?

For example if I have three schemas in my database:

- **dbo**
- **green**
- **red**

I have two database logins [**RedLogin**] and [**GreenLogin**].
These connect to my database using respective database users [**RedUser**] and [**GreenUser**]. These users are members of the respective database roles [**RedRole**] and [**GreenRole**].

- [**RedUser**] has a default schema of [**red**].
- [**GreenUser**] has a default schema of [**green**].
- [**RedRole**] has execute permission on [**dbo**] and select permission on the [**red**] schema.
- [**GreenRole**] has execute permission on [**dbo**] and select permission on the [**green**] schema.
- In the [**green**] schema I have a table called [**User**].
- In the [**red**] schema I have a table called [**User**].
- In the [**dbo**] schema I have a stored procedure called [**User_GetAll**] that runs

  SELECT * FROM USER;

What I would like is:

- For users who login with [**Redlogin**] and call the [**User_GetAll**] get all users from the [**red**].[**User**] table.
- For users who login with [**Greenlogin**] and call the [**User_GetAll**] get all users from the [**green**].[**User**] table.

Is this even possible? If so what is the best way to achieve it, please? Thank you.

**Please note:** The scenario above is just to get a flavour of what I am trying to achieve. In the real project there are many tables and stored procedures that the solution will need to be applied to.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible if you use the method `SCHEMA_NAME()` which returns the default schema of the caller (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175068.aspx)

So for your example:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + SCHEMA_NAME() + '.USER'
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
```

**Update:**

Oddly when I just did a quick test, calling `EXEC('SELECT * FROM USER')` it used the users default schema.  Perhaps you could try wrapping the contents of your stored procedure inside a single `EXEC('')`

For example:

```
EXEC('
    SELECT * FROM USER
    SELECT * FROM USER
    SELECT * FROM USER
    SELECT * FROM USER
')
```

Comment: That would be a valid solution, but not preferred as I would not really want to convert the allof the stored procs where his applies to execute a SQL string, if possible. Obviously if I have no other choice then this would be a good solution. Thank you.

Comment: Whilst still quite unpleasant in my tests you could get away with a single exec statement.

Comment: Looking good but I really want to avoid changing all my SPROCS to execute SQL in line as there are quite a few to do and some are quite long!

But will hold this in reserve!

Comment: Based on this https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/272964/using-default-schema-in-stored-procedures I think you are out of luck.

Comment: I think you are right. It looks as if I will need to duplicate the same Stored Proc to each schema. A nice anti-code reuse pattern that will be!

Database programming really is a second class citizen when you are used to programming in modern languages like .net.

It is a bit of a shame that SQL Server has not moved into the 21st century.